# How to add or delete a data from a single column at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am updating a single column of database with an array @$new=implode(',',$_POST['new']);

I am using query which is working fine

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE events SET std_list=CONCAT( std_list, ',".$new."') WHERE id='".$district."' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Now I also want to delete some data from the same column before adding new data to it .. for example column name std_list contain value 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  and a another variable $a contains 4,5,6 and $new=4,5. I want to delete 4,5,6 from column and want to add only 4,5 to it.

Comment: If `$new = 4,5,10`, what shud happen???

Comment: than add 4,5,10 to the column but delete 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to remove `$a` from `$std_list` but preserve values from `$new`.

```
$std_list = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
$a = '4,5,6';
$new = '4,5';

// Create arrays from values
$std_list_array = explode(',', $std_list);
$a_array = explode(',', $a);
$new_array = explode(',', $new);

// Remove values from $a
$values = array_diff($std_list_array, $a_array);

// Add values from $new
$values = array_merge($values, $new_array);

// Only keep unique values
$values = array_unique($values);

// Sort (maybe?)
sort($values);

// Convert to string
$values = implode(',', $values);

// string(15) "1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9"
var_dump($values);
```

You can then insert `$values` into the database. I've written this using mysqli [since mysql_query is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE events SET std_list = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $values, $district);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Test the code here: http://ideone.com/e3THDV

Comment: it is deleting only last value of array .. otherwise working fine